# Ability to view your own questions

Tags: feature-request, android-app

The app doesn't have a way to show your own questions. It would be nice to get a quick handle to those.

Answer (score 3):

It does, though. Just type `user:me` in the search field (it's automatically limited to questions only), and voila:

[image]

Comment: This trick also works on the iOS Stack Exchange app, and should work online.